# Year Structure Built of housing units

Tags: census, real-estate

I need to find the age of housing units? where specifically should I look and download a GIS file

Comment: You will need to be more specific. Are you looking for building ages for a particular geographic area?

Answer (score 2):

The American Community Survey has [table B25034](https://censusreporter.org/tables/B25034/), which has columns for each decade from the 1940's to current (and another for "1939 or earlier"). Each column estimates the number of housing units in the given geography built in that decade.

You can download this data as GIS from [Census Reporter](https://censusreporter.org), and probably also from [American FactFinder](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml).

For reference, here's a list of American Community Survey tables (as of the 2010-2014 5 year data release) which refer to the year housing units were built. Links are to Census Reporter "table" pages.

- **B25034**: [Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25034/)
- **B25035**: [Median Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25035/)
- **B25036**: [Tenure by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25036/)
- **B25037**: [Median Year Structure Built by Tenure](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25037/)
- **B25050**: [Plumbing Facilities by Occupants Per Room by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25050/)
- **B25107**: [Median Value by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25107/)
- **B25108**: [Aggregate Value (Dollars) by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25108/)
- **B25111**: [Median Gross Rent by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25111/)
- **B25112**: [Aggregate Gross Rent (Dollars) by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25112/)
- **B25126**: [Tenure by Age of Householder by Year Structure Built](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25126/)
- **B25127**: [Tenure by Year Structure Built by Units in Structure](http://censusreporter.org/tables/B25127/)